# Stream pricing from oanda V20 rest api using python requests

Tags: python, python-2.7, rest, python-requests, algorithmic-trading

I'm trying to [stream the price](http://developer.oanda.com/rest-live-v20/pricing-ep/) of an instrument from Oandas' V20 rest api but with not much success. I am using python requests as that worked for regular get requests. Here is where i have got to:

```
import requests
url = 'https://stream-fxpractice.oanda.com/v3/accounts/MY_ACCOUNT_ID/pricing?instruments=EUR_USD'
head = {'Content-type':"application/json",
        'Accept-Datetime-Format':"RFC3339",
        'Authorization':"Bearer MY_ACCESS8TOKEN"}


r = requests.get(url, headers=head, stream=True)
print(r)

for line in r.iter_lines():

    if line:
        decoded_line = line.decode('utf-8')
        print(json.loads(decoded_line))
```

The response error code is 405 meaning the method is not supported.
What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your URL is not valid (see [developer.oanda.com/rest-live-v20/pricing-ep/](http://developer.oanda.com/rest-live-v20/pricing-ep/) ),
it **should be:**

```
url_OK = 'https://stream-fxpractice.oanda.com/v3/accounts/MY_ACCOUNT_ID/pricing/stream?instruments=EUR_USD'
```

instead of:

```
urlNOT = 'https://stream-fxpractice.oanda.com/v3/accounts/MY_ACCOUNT_ID/pricing?instruments=EUR_USD'
//        |||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||vvvvvvvv
// _OK = 'https://stream-fxpractice.oanda.com/v3/accounts/MY_ACCOUNT_ID/pricing/stream?instruments=EUR_USD'
```

If you don't want the hassle of constructing URL's,
you could use one of the V20 bindings:
https://github.com/search?utf8=%E2%9C%93&q=v20&type=

Check for instance the examplecode in those repositories, for example:
https://github.com/hootnot/oandapyV20-examples

Answer (score 0):

### Step 0.: validate you access credentials:

Using a default OANDA **`curl`** example, validate your access credentials:

```
curl \
  -H "Content-Type: application/json" \
  -H "Authorization: Bearer <AUTHENTICATION TOKEN>" \
  "https://api-fxtrade.oanda.com/v3/accounts/<ACCOUNT>/pricing?instruments=EUR_USD%2CUSD_CAD"
```

**CASE isERR:** proceed to OANDA Support for fixing your issues with invalid credentials.

**CASE wasOK:** proceed to **Step 1.**

---

### Step 1.: replicate the `curl` call syntax AS-IS inside a one-shot python

nothing added, nothing excluded. Ought provide the same results as in Step 0.

**CASE isERR:** review your one-shot python-code, so as to meet 1:1 the working OANDA specification, already proved to be working in Step 0.

- Review OANDA Service Status, using `curl` below:
  `curl http://api-status.oanda.com/api/v1/services`
- Review reported Error details.

**CASE wasOK:** proceed to **Step 2.**

---

### Step 2.: extend the python code so as to request and process response

yet, keep in mind, not to go beyond OANDA stated maximum count of requests per day and similar restrictive limits, which ought be handled with care.

**CASE isERR:** Review OANDA Service Status, using `curl` below and possible reported Error details:

```
curl http://api-status.oanda.com/api/v1/services
```

**CASE wasOK:** Congrats, your pricing-source got working end-to-end up to the specifications.

---

### Error 405 is not a *"not supported"* service BUT "not allowed"

> **405 Method Not Allowed**
>   
>   A **“405 Method Not Allowed”** response may be returned from the v20 REST API when the client is attempting to access an API endpoint with an HTTP method that is not supported. The response Content-Type will be application/json and has the following schema:

```
{
    # 
    # The code of the error that has occurred.  This field may not be returned
    # for some errors.
    # 
    errorCode : (string),

    # 
    # The human-readable description of the error that has occurred.
    # 
    errorMessage : (string, required)
}
```